# Trying to solve a simple prolog assignment

Tags: prolog

This is my assignment clue:

Four drivers: Norma, Andy, Edward, and Olivia have been charged with four traffic violations: running a stop sign, speeding, making an illegal left turn, and running a red light. Use the clues to find out which law each suspect violated.

Clues

1. Norma did not run either a red light or a stop sign.
2. Andy was never stopped for speeding.
3. Edward made an illegal left turn.
4. Olivia was always careful to stop at a stop sign.

I need to solve it using prolog.

I have tried the following code so far:

```
violatated(Violation):-
member(Violation,[speeding,leftturn,stop,red]).

solve(S):-
S=[[Name1,Violation1],
   [Name2,Violation2],
   [Name3,Violation3],
   [Name4,Violation4]],

    %five drivers: Norma, Andy, Edward, Olivia
Name1 = norma,
Name2 = andy,
Name3 = edward,
Name4 = olivia,

violated(Violation1), violated(Violation2), violated(Violation3), violated(Violation4),
Violation1 \== Violation2, Violation1 \== Violation3, Violation1 \== Violation4,
Violation2 \== Violation1, Violation2 \== Violation3, Violation2 \== Violation4,
Violation3 \== Violation1, Violation3 \== Violation2, Violation3 \== Violation4,
Violation4 \== Violation1, Violation4 \== Violation2, Violation4 \== Violation3,

%Edward made an illegal left turn
Violation3 == leftturn,

%Norma did not run either a red light or a stop sign
Violation1 \== red,
Violation1 \== stop,

%Andy was never stopped for speeding.
Violation2 \== speeding,

%Olivia was always careful to stop at a stop sign
Violation4 \== stop.
```

Excuse me for being a newbie in prolog!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have simplified your code a bit:

```
solve(S):-
    S=[[norma,Violation1],
       [andy,Violation2],
       [edward,Violation3],
       [olivia,Violation4]],

    permutation([speeding,leftturn,stop,red], [Violation1,Violation2,Violation3,Violation4]),

    %Edward made an illegal left turn
    Violation3 = leftturn,

    %Norma did not run either a red light or a stop sign
    Violation1 \= red,
    Violation1 \= stop,

    %Andy was never stopped for speeding.
    Violation2 \= speeding,

    %Olivia was always careful to stop at a stop sign
    Violation4 \= stop.
```

with that:

```
?- solve(S).
S = [[norma, speeding], [andy, stop], [edward, leftturn], [olivia, red]] ;
false.
```

but your code seems ok, just a typo to correct:

```
violated(Violation):-
    member(Violation,[speeding,leftturn,stop,red]).
```

instead of `violatated(Violation):-`